# Retrive posts thumbnail in original size

Tags: theme-development

Hi I am trying to integrate a jquery gallery into my wordpress theme.The gallery will have a caption that will display the posts title and excerpt content.

What I am thinking to do is create a custom query for the posts and retrieve the posts thumbnail image aldo I would like to be able to get the image in it's full size that is stored in the media gallery.

Is there a way I can achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full'); ?>
```

[codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail#thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail#thumbnail)

Answer (score 0):

you mean this?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src